# Do you know good JMonkeyEngine tutorials and docs?

Tags: java, documentation, jmonkeyengine

I'm interested in JMonkey for some fun projects, but when I search Google to find tutorials and docs, I can only find either really basic and/or incomplete stuff, like these on http://jmonkeyengine.org/, or really specific ones. Do you know some "from beginner to expert" tutorial for JMonkey?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the best I found is this one:

http://www.theprogrammersweblog.com/2008/12/3d-game-programming-in-java-using.html

It's incomplete (but maybe it will be completed someday), but 11 parts are already available.

The aim is to create a complete Asteroid game.

Comment: It would be good to note that the linked article is from the end of 2008 and, as such, is using a version of jMonkeyEngine that is out of date as compared to the current (as of mid-2011) version 3

Answer (score 14):

http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3 has a complete series of tutorials for jME3. They just haven't been accessible via google until now..

http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme2:jme2 has a series of tutorials for the now community-supported old jME2

Comment: Both of these are dead links

Answer (score 2):

Hey check this Game Making [PDF](http://www.tukano.it/documents/rollmadness.pdf)